# Issue converting dd.mm.yyyy to UK date format using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have dates in the following format :-

```
01.01.2019
01.02.2019
01.03.2019
14.03.2019
```

and I would like these in UK date format of dd/mm/yyyy, using VBA conversion.

I attempted to use a `REPLACE`, changing "." to "/", but this outputs the dates as :-

```
01/01/2019
02/01/2019
03/01/2019
14/03/2019
```

Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Do you have *dates* and it is a matter of formatting or do you have *strings* that look like a date?

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: @FunThomas The cell format is General currently and the cell's contents is "01.01.2019".

Comment: There is your problem. Cell formats and excel's keenness for American dates is what you always have to look out for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below code loop column A & convert the date in column B. Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Year As String, Month As String, Day As String, WholeString As String
    Dim i As Long, Lastrow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To Lastrow

            WholeString = .Range("A" & i).Value
            Year = Right(WholeString, 4)
            Month = Mid(WholeString, 4, 2)
            Day = Left(WholeString, 2)

            With .Range("B" & i)
                .Value = CDate(Day & "/" & Month & "/" & Year)
                .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
            End With

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

What does this do for you? I'm curious if it would return `dd/mm/yyyy` for you:

```
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
    .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlDMYFormat)
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End With
```

Comment: This will not work if the data is a string. Hence my question about what the OP has

Comment: @FunThomas, yes I quickly realized, thanks for the heads up. Changed my answer.